# Multiple viewholder in recyclerview

Tags: android-recyclerview, android-viewholder

I have two completely different layouts. One with image view, the other with text view. I want to be able to use both layout in a recyclerview. How do I go about it please. Help

Answer (score 0):

Yoou have to override the getItemViewType function of the RecyclerAdapter. From that you return an Integer which you capture inside the onCreateViewHolder. Inside there you choose which ViewHolder you inflate.

```
@Override
public int getItemViewType(int position) {
    if (TextUtils.isEmpty(employees.get(position).getEmail())) {
        return TYPE_CALL;

    } else {
        return TYPE_EMAIL;
    }
}
```

```
@Override
public RecyclerView.ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(@NonNull ViewGroup viewGroup, int viewType) {
    View view;
    if (viewType == TYPE_CALL) { // for call layout
        view = LayoutInflater.from(context).inflate(R.layout.item_call, viewGroup, false);
        return new CallViewHolder(view);

    } else { // for email layout
        view = LayoutInflater.from(context).inflate(R.layout.item_email, viewGroup, false);
        return new EmailViewHolder(view);
    }
}
```